# Where has Lucene.Net.Highlight gone?

Tags: lucene.net

I'm trying to figure out where `Lucene.Net.Highlight.dll` and the corresponding formatting classes (such as `SimpleHTMLFormatter`) have gone to.

The last time I downloaded Lucene.Net this assembly was packaged up in the zip file, however this isn't the case with the latest download I could find and I couldn't find any other references to it on [this page](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/), or any other page for that matter.

Does anyone know where it is hiding?

Comment: +1 I was about to ask the exact same question. I got lucene.net off the nuget `<package id="Lucene" version="2.9.2.2" />` and the damn `Lucene.Net.Search.Highlight` has disappered!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no binary releases of the recent Lucene.Net versions.

You will have to check it out from : https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/lucene.net/trunk/C#/contrib/Highlighter.Net using SVN and build the DLL yourself.

**Update**

The contrib package can now be reliably downloaded via Nuget, in binary release.

http://nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net.Contrib/

Comment: fyi Lucene.Net has moved back into the incubator - [Incubator SVN](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/incubator/lucene.net/?pathrev=1069572) it's mostly a mirror of above right now, execpt it also has the arabic analyzer.

Comment: Why are there no more binary releases? Is that an indicator of Lucene.NET development petering out??

Comment: Ok Im answering my comment above : Lucene.NET is not closing down, instead it's back in action, thanks to [Jeff Atwood](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/stack-overflow-search-now-81-less-crappy/) and especially [Troy & these](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-lucene-net-dev/201108.mbox/browser) folks.

Comment: Just fixing the link: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/lucene.net/trunk/C%23/contrib/Highlighter.Net - the # gets eaten if it's used as-is (at least in Firefox)

Answer (score 8):

The Highlighter is now part of the Lucene.Contrib package in NuGet.