# Can't find a few things in Lucene.NET

Tags: lucene.net

I'm having a hard time finding some classes in Lucene.NET. I'm using v. 2.9.2 and cannot find the Highliter, QueryScorer classes. (referenced in this question as well: [Highlighting whole sentence in Lucene.net 2.9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549589/highlighting-whole-sentence-in-lucene-net-2-9-2))

I've searched through the source and such and cannot find them, but somehow I keep coming across people who are using it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957666/where-has-lucene-net-highlight-gone

Comment: thanks @iandayman. Somehow when I found that answer it didn't what the answer was. When denis answered, it sunk in. Hurr.Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the source [from here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/lucene.net/tags/Lucene.Net_2_9_2_RC2/contrib/) using [SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html). But there is no binary, you have to compile it by yourself.