# Where is ChainedFilter class in Lucene .NET 3.0.3?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

It was in *Lucene.Net.Analyzers.dll* in version 2.9.4. But i can't find this class in version 3.0.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mindas: here is my comment since I cannot add a normal comment: how to access this ChainedFilter class? I have downloaded the package but there is no namespace like Lucene.Net.Contrib, or no other namespace which allows me to reach the ChainedFilter class. This seems silly but I am stuck!

UPDATE: There is a bug in the binaries from Nuget as well as zip files uploaded on apache site for Lucene.net. I downloaded the source and noticed that the ChainedFilter.cs class is present in the Apache-Lucene.Net-3.0.3-RC2.src\src\contrib\Analyzers\Filters folder, but this folder is surprisingly not a part of the Contrib.Analyzers project. That is why it was missing from the generated binaries.

Comment: Okay, I guess my knowledge ends here ;-( Probably the wisest thing would be to contact guys @ Nuget or write an email to the Lucene.net mailing list.

Comment: Also, I upvoted this answer so you should be able to comment now as you've got 50+ pts ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Rephrasing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957666/where-has-lucene-net-highlight-gone), you can either build it yourself or use Nuget to get the binaries.

http://nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net.Contrib/

`ChainedFilter` should be under contrib/misc.

Comment: Install-Package Lucene.net.Contrib resolves to Lucene.Net.Contrib 3.0.3 which does not have ChainedFilter under contrib/misc. There is no even Lucene.Net.Contrib.Analyzers.Filters namespace in that package. I don't see how Nuget be used to get it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is in **org.apache.lucene.misc.ChainedFilter** in Lucene 3.x.